# MVC.net 4 how to use ckeditor with textarea inside Jtable popup

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable

I try to use the ckeditor with popup edit item of jtable but it not appears.
and chrome browser not showing error when i debug it.

this is my code !! my textarea name is "Mota"

```js
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jtablescripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jtablescripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
...
   fields: {
      MoTa: {
      title: 'MoTa',
                    type: 'textarea',
                    list: false,
                    sorting: false,
                    formCreated: function (event, data) {
                        //$('textarea#Edit-MoTa').ckeditor();
                        CKEDITOR.replace('MoTa', { toolbar: '1', htmlEncodeOutput: true });
                    },
                    formClosed: function (event, data) {
                        var editor = jQuery("textarea#Edit-MoTa").ckeditorGet();
                        editor.destroy();
                    }
                }
...
</script>


<script>CKEDITOR.replace('GhiChu', { toolbar: '1', htmlEncodeOutput: true });</script>
```

thanks for help me

Answer (score 1):

check sample code here >>>

```js
$('#templates').jtable({
   title: 'Email Templates',
   paging: true,
   sorting: true,
   multiSorting: true,
   defaultSorting: 'TemplateCode ASC',
   actions: {
    listAction: '@Url.Action("List")',
    updateAction: '@Url.Action("Update")',
    createAction: '@Url.Action("Create")',
    deleteAction: '@Url.Action("Delete")'
   },
   fields: {
    EmailTemplateID: {
     key: true,
     list: false
    },
    TemplateCode: {
     title: 'Template Code'
    },
    Subject: {
     title: 'Subject',
    },
    Body: {
     title: 'Body',
     type: 'textarea',
     list: false
    },
    SenderName: {
     title: 'Sender Name'
    },
    SenderEmail: {
     title: 'Sender Email'
    }
   },
   formCreated: function (event, data) {
    body = CKEDITOR.replace('Body', { width: '600px' });
    $($(data.form.parent()).parent()).css('left', '300px');
    $($(data.form.parent()).parent()).css('top', '30px');
    data.form.find('input[name="TemplateCode"]').addClass('validate[required]');
    data.form.find('input[name="SenderEmail"]').addClass('validate[custom[email]]');
    data.form.validationEngine();
   },
   formSubmitting: function (event, data) {
    $('textarea#Edit-Body').val(body.getData());
    return data.form.validationEngine('validate');
   },
   formClosed: function (event, data) {
                data.form.validationEngine('hide');
                data.form.validationEngine('detach');
            },
   animationsEnabled: isEnabled
  });
```